# Projekt using Guice runs in Eclipse, on terminal doesn't

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, guice

i need help at get a given project running. The project is: http://code.google.com/p/opennetinf/

I follow the instructions in the documentation and get the project running in Eclipse. Now i want to run this project from a terminal. On the terminal is get a big exception after some time in the startup of the project. The first lines of the log4j output are similar to the output in the eclipse console.
The exception is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at netinf.node.cache.peerside.PeersideCacheModule.provideNetworkCaches(PeersideCacheModule.java:64)
  while locating java.util.List<netinf.node.cache.peerside.PeersideCache>
    for parameter 0 at netinf.node.cache.CachingInterceptor.setPeersideCaches(CachingInterceptor.java:81)
  while locating netinf.node.cache.CachingInterceptor
  at netinf.node.module.StandardNodeModule.provideResolutionInterceptors(StandardNodeModule.java:125)
  while locating netinf.node.resolution.ResolutionInterceptor[]
    for parameter 0 at netinf.node.resolution.impl.ResolutionControllerImpl.initReslolutionInterceptors(ResolutionControllerImpl.java:442)
  while locating netinf.node.resolution.impl.ResolutionControllerImpl
  while locating netinf.node.resolution.ResolutionController
    for parameter 0 at netinf.node.api.impl.NetInfNodeImpl.setResolutionController(NetInfNodeImpl.java:95)
  while locating netinf.node.api.impl.NetInfNodeImpl
  while locating netinf.node.api.NetInfNode

1 error
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:767)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
    at netinf.node.StarterNode.start(StarterNode.java:126)
    at netinf.node.StarterNode.main(StarterNode.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
    at com.google.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
    at com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:101)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
    at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.warn(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.warn(Log.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setFailed(AbstractLifeCycle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at netinf.node.cache.peerside.PeersideAccessServer.start(PeersideAccessServer.java:64)
    at netinf.node.cache.peerside.PeersideCache.<init>(PeersideCache.java:79)
    at netinf.node.cache.peerside.PeersideCacheModule.provideNetworkCaches(PeersideCacheModule.java:77)
    ... 53 more
```

So what have i done:
I exported the project via Eclipse Export Dialog (Export -> Runnable Jar). The library handling is irrelevant. With each of the three methods i get the same exception.

So my Question is: What does this exception tell me? And how can i resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a classpath error relating to Slf4j. Looking at the [build file](http://code.google.com/p/opennetinf/source/browse/build/build.xml#74), this project seems to use Slf4j 1.5.6.

Make sure that the following 2 jar files are in your classpath:

```
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
```

Also make sure that there are no other slf4j jars in the classpath.

Comment: Hey Chris B that was the point. There was an old slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar in the lib directory. I deleted. It now it works. Thank you.